# Maximum length of WHERE clause with IN statement

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, sql

I need to get all features from feature class where their field value matches to input array. To achive this one may set IQueryFilter.WhereClause property similar to 'FIELD_NAME IN (array[0], array[1], array[2],...., array[n-1])'. But the size of array might be quite big.

The questions are how long IN statement can be? And can I define it at runtime?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you doing this via code, or in the User interface? How is the array currently stored?

Comment: This depends on the underlying database. Note that besides the total query length, some databases also impose restrictions on the count of elements in a single `IN` clause.

Comment: I'm doing it through the C# code. Array is rarefied. 

>"some databases also impose restrictions on the count of elements in a single IN clause." - I expect this. That's why I'm asking can I define this at runtime.

Comment: You'd need to specify which RDBMS you're using in order to get an answer

Comment: Now we are targeting on Oracle. But I'd like to support SQL and personal gdb also.

Comment: "SQL" isn't an RDBMS, but "SQL-Server" is (Microsoft product). Personal geodatabase isn't SQL-based (Microsoft Jet/Access). They each have different IN clause limitations.

Comment: Related: [ArcObjects: Alternative workflow to using a SQL query with over 1000 values in IN statement](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/11943/753)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exact number of explicit terms in an IN clause varies by RDBMS.  Oracle limits you to [1000 explicit terms](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/430758?start=0&tstart=0), while the SQL-Server doc only mentions "[several thousands](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx)".

The real issue is that an IN clause is not very efficient.   If you have more than a few hundred terms, you'd likely get a faster query by loading a temporary table with the values, then doing a join (or an IN to a subselect, which is implemented as a join).  In ArcGIS, selection sets can be used for this purpose (vice explicitly creating a temporary table, but the implementation is the same).

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find a way how to find out exact size of IN statement and then safaly build it but I have found a workaround. I have reduced described problem to search the rows satisfying the following where clause: `(OBJECTID IN (123, 456,789)) AND FIELD1 = x AND FIELD2 = y AND ...`. I.e. the statement has IN statement with very big list of numbers and arbitrary AND statements.

Here is the workaround:

1. I used `ITable.Select` to create empty selection set.
2. Then populate this set with `ISelectionSet.AddArray` with necessary OIDs. It allows to avoid from using IN statement like in WHERE clause `OBJECTID IN (123, 456, 789)`
3. Apply additional additional where caluses to selection set `ISelectionSet.SearchSearch(IQueryFilter, bool, out ICursor)`.

Answer (score 0):

How can the below be replaced to use a variable in place of hard code values 
filter.WhereClause = featureClass.OIDFieldName + " IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)";

string strFIDS="1,2,3,4,5,6";

Does the below work ?
filter.WhereClause = featureClass.OIDFieldName + " IN (strFIDS)";